# How can I vertically and horizontally align text over an image?

Tags: css

I have a simple image of a ball which I am using as a background. I would like to overlay text. The text will be a number, i.e. a lottery number.

I have tried various methods but cannot find a solution, e.g.

CSS

```
#container {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
}

#image {    
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
#text {
  position:absolute;    
  color:black;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  top:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.powerball-lottery-blog.com/img/balls/ball_white_40.gif"/>
    <p id="text">37</p>
</div>
```

I just cannot get the number to align vertically and horizontally in the ball.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a background image instead. Much more reliable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#container {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}

#text {
    margin: 0;
    color:black;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(http://www.powerball-lottery-blog.com/img/balls/ball_white_40.gif) no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <p id="text">37</p> </div>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the image. Here's what I would do:

```
#container {
  background:url('http://www.powerball-lottery-blog.com/img/balls/ball_white_40.gif') no-repeat;
  height:400px; width:400px;
}
#text {
  color:#000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;
}
```

Now, you have to figure out the text height. The formula is (`#container`.height/2)-(`#text`.height/2). You should use JavaScript, like:

```
//center.js
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function center(innerElement){
  var e = innerElement, p = e.parentNode, ih, oh;
  if(window.getComputedStyle){
    ih = getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('height');
    oh = getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue('height');
  }
  else{
    ih = e.currentStyle.height;
    oh = p.currentStyle.height;
  }
  e.style.margin = oh/2-ih/2+'px auto';
}
```

Now your HTML can contain:

```
<!--DOCTYPE and head with style here-->
<body>
  <div id='container'>
    <div id='text'>Line 1<br />Line 2</div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='center.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    center(E('text'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think in this case [CSS line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) will do the vertical centering much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `#image` as absolutely positioned and set fixed widths for the container and `#image` to match the image size like so:

```
#container {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    position:relative;
}

#image {    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
#text {
    color:black;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

**But personally**, I'd set your image to the background of an element - that way you can eliminate a bit of HTML as well.

New HTML

```
<div id="ball">37</div>
```

New CSS

```
#ball{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.powerball-lottery-blog.com/img/balls/ball_white_40.gif") center center no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/2WAAj/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
#container
    {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
    }
#ball    
    {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url("http://www.powerball-lottery-blog.com/img/balls/ball_white_40.gif"); 
    }
#text
    {
    position:relative;    
    color:black;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;    
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:3px;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="ball">
                    <div id="text">   
                        <p id="text">37</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ball">
                    <div id="text">   
                        <p id="text">&nbsp;3</p> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div id="ball">
                    <div id="text">   
                        <p id="text">15</p> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div id="ball">
                    <div id="text">   
                        <p id="text">17</p> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div id="ball">
                    <div id="text">   
                        <p id="text">27</p> 
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </td>
            <td>  
                    <img src="http://www.lotterynumbers.name/media/images/misc/its-a-rollover.png"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a couple more balls to show you what it looks like. The **container div** at **400px** by **400px** will accommodate 10 balls across by 10 down. The **float:left** assures that it will wrap around if you simply copy/paste the **ball divs**.

Also, for single digits, you will want to add a non-breaking space (which I did) or a "0" (i.e. "04" instead of "4") to make sure they center correctly like the two-digit numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I got the above working fine. Only one more thing now. I wanted to put an image and some text to the side of this. So, to do that I set up a table with the following row:
<tr><td>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="ball">
          <div id="text">   
              <p id="text">37</p> 
          </div>
      </div>
      [x 5 more numbers]
   </div>
</td><td>
<img src="http://www.lotterynumbers.name/media/images/misc/its-a-rollover.png">
</td></td>
Some text here
</td></tr>
It doesn't look pretty! How can I align the image and the text?
Thanks, Neil.

Comment: Here is the page which I am trying to get working:
http://www.powerball-lottery-results.com/winning-numbers/
As you can see, I cannot get the "rollover" image and the "jackpot" text to align correctly. Any ideas? Thanks, Neil.

Comment: If you want to wrap it all up in a table to get it aligned, the numbered balls would be in one `<td>` and the image or text in another.

Comment: I updated my solution to include the table. I hope this helps.